# Scroll div on pagescroll but stop after certain amount

Tags: javascript

I have currently got an element to scroll on page scroll and I am looking to get it to stop after around 750px as it currently overlaps the footer on smaller monitors.

I have found a couple of other examples which would require some restructuring of my code which I am trying to avoid, as the various other examples have to have certain divs relevant to eachother in order to stop the scrolling div at a certain point on the page.

My current script is as below and wrks great, only I am unsure as to edit this to stop the div at a certain point:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var btn = $('.overview-wrap');
var btnPosTop = btn.offset().top;
var win = $(window);
win.scroll(function(e){
    var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop >= btnPosTop){
        btn.css({position:'fixed',top:0,marginTop:0});
    }else if(btn.css('position') === 'fixed'){
        btn.css({position:'',top:'',marginTop:'20px'});
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I hate dealing directly with the DOM for things like position, because it's so variable. Check out the [jquery-position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) library for a nice abstraction on top of the dom.

Comment: I have since found another method which suits my requirements, but thank you anyway.